# How to deploy multiple juju services on the same server with MaaS

Tags: juju, maas

I have 6 services that I need to deploy with 5 physical servers. Would it be ok to deploy juju gui with haproxy? How would you deploy multiple services to one server. I saw some documentation for deploying to same server but they were for openstack and I couldn't find anything for MAAS.

I have tried both

```
juju deploy --to 0
```

and

```
juju deploy --force-machine 0
```

I get `unrecognized arguments`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got juju deploy --to working. I had to update to the latest stable version of juju.

It would be helpful to add that to the MaaS documentation for juju quick start.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use jitsu to achieve the same with an older version. I am using an older juju version and I downloaded a jitsu deb that I installed and used successfully.

Answer (score 0):

i've used that to deploy more services on the same node

```
$: juju deploy --to 0 "service1" "service2" "service3"
$: juju deploy --to 1 "service4"
```